# Android monitor won't recognize my Android (Galaxy S2) on Windows 8

Tags: android, windows-8, cordova

I'm trying to build and run a cordova project on my Galaxy S2. I'm having trouble getting my windows 8 HP Pavilion intel core i5 laptop to recognize the phone. Here's the two things that have worked for me:

A. I've gone through the whole process easily on my windows 7 desktop, so it isn't my phone's settings

B. I can transfer files from my phone on the windows 8 machine (ie its icon appears in My Computer), so its not a simple connection issue

I've followed [these instructions](http://rendykstan.github.io/blog/2013/03/20/install-android-usb-driver-on-windows-8/), which look pretty identical to the [official windows 7 instruction](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) for some reason. The result was that my computer told me "Windows was unable to install your SAMSUNG_Android".

Going to the android `monitor` never shows my phone when i plug it in. I also tried installing directly from sdk/extras/google/usb_driver/android_winusb.inf (it tells me "The operation completed successfully"), then restarted the computer. No Dice.

I've tried MPT and PTP modes. I tried the Galaxy S2, S3, and S4 (that's what was around at the time). None worked. If it helps, I also wasn't able to get my phone to connect to my computer via bluetooth for some reason - this is probably unrelated tho.

So what gives? How do I do this? Help!

Comment: Have you tried installing Samsung Kies?

Comment: No I haven't - I'll do that right now. Why do you think that would help?

Comment: Samsung Kies installs the USB drivers for Sasmsung devices. Chances are that your Win8 machine isn't recognizing the device because the correct driver isn't installed. It's worth a shot :)

Comment: Oh shiit it worked! Thanks a million! Write that up as an answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably install [Samsung Kies](http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/) since you are using a Samsung device. This will install all Samsung related drivers which should enable your adb to recognize the device.